Is it possible to combine parameterised update statements?
I have a large number of similar but unique update statements, where the same fields are being updated with different values, ie.
UPDATE tbl SET field1 = "x" WHERE pk = 1;
UPDATE tbl SET field1 = "y" WHERE pk = 2;

These are being sent as parameterised queries using DbCommand. Is there anything I can do to combine these, or otherwise optimise the update process?
Edit: I can confirm that @MarcGravell's comment above does work, and allows me to concatenate queries even when the updated fields are different in each query.

what happens when you do the most obvious thing here, i.e. UPDATE tbl SET field1 = @val0 WHERE pk = @id0; UPDATE tbl SET field1 = @val1 WHERE pk = @id1; with 4 parameters?

CASE WHEN might be an option like shown here

If you also need to change always the same column like in the linked question i would flag this as duplicate.

@MarcGravell - Minor correction: those aren't parameters, they're variables. Parameters would require prepared statements, but MySQL does not support multi-query in prepared statements.

You could use a joined update with a VALUES clause
UPDATE tbl
JOIN (VALUES
    ROW(@pk1, @v1),
    ROW(@pk2, @v2)
) AS v(pk, field1) ON v.pk = tbl.pk
SET tbl.field1 = v.field1;


You should include a join condition.

Thanks for the info, I hadn't seen this format before.
